# Cloudflare Wordpress network settings?

Tags: wordpress, dns, cloudflare

I move my dns to Cloudflare. Everything good but Wordpress Network site's don't work. I guess i must add CNAME record to Cloudflare like "*.site.com" How i fix that?

Main site: site.com
WP network site: market.site.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CNAME-records are easy to manage, if you will be hosting 100’s of sites on your network. If you change IP of your WordPress server, say change in hosting service, then you will need to make update IP address for your own CNAME record only.

You can add or edit CNAMEs by going to the 'DNS Settings' for your domain. How to add is given [here](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/360019093151-How-do-I-add-a-CNAME-record-)

If still you cant find just open a ticket [here](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/requests/new)

Comment: Thank you for answer. But i can't understand. I added  CNAME record like "*.site.com" to address. But it doesn't work.